# How to disable Chart axis autosize

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, scale, autoresize

I need to stop autosizing (or autoscaling) of Y Axis in c# chart and set it manually.
Any advice? Thanks

Comment: What kind of chart? In what kind of application? ASP.NET? Winforms? WPF? Something else?

Comment: In windows forms application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the minimum and maximum of the Y axis like so:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 10;
```